# why is zsh not expanding this glob defined inside a function '(:a)'

Tags: zsh, wildcards, assignment

The second line of the script only works if I trigger glob expansion by executing `echo`. I can't understand why. Here's the command and it's execution to give some context.

Function definition:

```
~/ cat ~/.zsh/includes/ascii2gif
ascii2gif () {
        setopt extendedglob
        input=$(echo ${1}(:a))
        _path=${input:h}
        input_f=${input:t}
        output_f=${${input_f}:r}.gif
        cd $_path
        nerdctl run --rm -v $_path:/data asciinema/asciicast2gif -s 2 -t solarized-dark $input_f $output_f
}
```

Activate function debugging for ascii2gif function..

```
~/ typeset -f -t ascii2gif
```

Debugged function execution:

```
~/ ascii2gif ./demo.cast
+ascii2gif:1> input=+ascii2gif:1> echo /Users/b/demo.cast
+ascii2gif:1> input=/Users/b/demo.cast
+ascii2gif:2> _path=/Users/b
+ascii2gif:3> input_f=demo.cast
+ascii2gif:4> output_f=demo.gif
+ascii2gif:5> cd /Users/b
+_direnv_hook:1> trap -- '' SIGINT
+_direnv_hook:2> /Users/b/homebrew/bin//direnv export zsh
+_direnv_hook:2> eval ''
+_direnv_hook:3> trap - SIGINT
+ascii2gif:6> nerdctl run --rm -v /Users/b:/data asciinema/asciicast2gif -s 2 -t solarized-dark demo.cast demo.gif
==> Loading demo.cast...
==> Spawning PhantomJS renderer...
==> Generating frame screenshots...
==> Combining 40 screenshots into GIF file...
==> Done.
```

I've tried numerous variations to try and force expansion such as `input=${~1}(:a)` etc, but to no avail. Any suggestions? Obviously the script works but seems sub-optimal.

Comment: The 2nd line `ascii2gif () {`?

Comment: And the first line `~/ cat ~/.zsh/includes/ascii2gif` does?

Comment: Unrelated: `setopt` and variable assignments have a global effect by default. When you change options for the purposes of a function, either use `setopt local_options` or, usually, use `emulate -L zsh` so that your function will work if some options you weren't thinking about have been changed from the default. Also make variables local with `local` (or `typeset`). Also it's probably a bad idea to change the current directory in this function. Or you could run the whole function in a subshell by putting `(…)` around the body instead of `{…}` (but still keep `emulate zsh`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the way you're trying to use [the `a` modifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) here is for globbing, and no globbing takes place in `var=WORD` (because globbing, in general, can result in multiple words, so it doesn't take place in contexts that expect a single word). So you're relying on globbing taking place inside the command substitution, and then assigning the result to the variable.

Since the `a` modifier can be used on parameter expansion but with a different way of applying it, you can try that:

```
input=${1:a}
```

For example:

```
% cd /tmp
% foo() { input=${1:a}; typeset -p input; }
% foo some-file
typeset -g input=/tmp/some-file
```

Comment: ah, such a small think when you know the right answer - thanks Gilles

Answer (score 4):

[/u muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/697350/65304) looks like the right way to go about this, but the reason *why* it's not expanding is that filename generation (globbing) does not take place in scalar assignments (it does in array assignments, because globs - in general - may return multiple matches):

From `man zshoptions`:

> ```
>    GLOB_ASSIGN <C>
>           If this option is set, filename generation  (globbing)  is  per‐
>           formed on the right hand side of scalar parameter assignments of
>           the form `name=pattern (e.g. `foo=*').  If the result  has  more
>           than  one  word  the  parameter  will become an array with those
>           words as arguments. This option is provided for  backwards  com‐
>           patibility  only: globbing is always performed on the right hand
>           side of array  assignments  of  the  form  `name=(value)'  (e.g.
>           `foo=(*)')  and  this form is recommended for clarity; with this
>           option set, it is not possible to  predict  whether  the  result
>           will be an array or a scalar.
> ```

So

```
$ zsh -c 'f=${1}(:a); echo $f' zsh file.txt
file.txt(:a)
```

but

```
$ zsh -c 'f=(${1}(:a)); echo $f' zsh file.txt
/home/steeldriver/dir/file.txt
```